# NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to cask cdap and Hadoop environment.

I'm creating a pipeline and I want to use a PySpark Program. I have all the script of the spark program and it works when I test it by command like, insted it doesn't if I try to copy- paste it in a cdap pipeline.

It gives me an error in the logs:

```
NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined
```

My script starts in this way:

```
from pyspark.sql import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim, to_date, year, month
sc= SparkContext()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you initialize findspark?

Comment: Sounds like you use Spark 1.x not 2.x. In that case you should either update or use `SQLContext`. Please post `sc.version` output.

Comment: @user8371915 Have similar problem, `SPARK_HOME=/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0`, `sc.version=2.1.0-mapr-1710`. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter Incorrect PYTHONPATH or similar property?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# ---Your code----
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Spark connects with the local running spark cluster through `SparkContext`. A better explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996767/5671433.

To initialise a `SparkSession`, a `SparkContext` has to be initialized.
One way to do that is to write a function that initializes all your contexts and a spark session.

```py
def init_spark(app_name, master_config):
    """
    :params app_name: Name of the app
    :params master_config: eg. local[4]
    :returns SparkContext, SQLContext, SparkSession:
    """
    conf = (SparkConf().setAppName(app_name).setMaster(master_config))

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    sql_ctx = SQLContext(sc)
    spark = SparkSession(sc)

    return (sc, sql_ctx, spark)
```

This can then be called as

```py
sc, sql_ctx, spark = init_spark("App_name", "local[4]")
```