Python,trying to run pyspark,but gives FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
I just trying ro run a simple code of pyspark,but alaways gave me winerror2.
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test_spark_app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
print(sc.version)
sc.stop()

Then i try to find where wrong is。This is the specific error content,may be there have some Chinese,it's just a name of the file.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pycharm\pythonProject2\第三阶段\py_spark\spark基础.py", line 11, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 195, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 417, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 99, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。

I try to read the context of SparkContext,but i can't understand where the problem is and i also don't understand what that designated file means.I just a beginner,so i don't know how to solve it.

It looks like it is trying to run some other program, but that program is not found on the PATH environment variable.

the issue is likely with the SparkContext naming, refer to this answer to see if that resolves the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996767/9267296
